# Make freestyle-render completely ignore objects

Tags: freestyle

I am trying to get the freestyle render to make a black line around all the monkey heads but as you can see in the image below. the render gets affected by the pink planes in the scene. The planes are in group called "Group.003" and that group is excluded from the freestyle. But the planes still stops the line from going all around the monkey heads. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Try clicking "silhouette" and "border" on and maybe "crease".  At least try different ones than what you have now.

Comment: I have tried that now and none of those options works the way I want. I want all the monkey heads to share one black outline around them all and I also don't want any black line on the money heads, only around them. Do you have any other ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Not offhand, but if you upload your file I'll try to see if I can find out what's going on.